# etc/apt/sources.list file for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, updates, 17.10

I am unable to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 as due to wrong links in sources.list file. I am able to update successfully as only some of the links are wrong. As Ubuntu 17.10 repositories are not yet moved to old-release, I am unable to update when i replace archive to old-release. And with unchanged sources.list file, some of the links are not working-

```
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages [8,531 kB] 
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

Can someone tell the solution, or post their sources.list file to check the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark) looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
```

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 18.04 looks the same as the above sources.list except all 5 times `artful` appears it is replaced by `bionic`

Make sure to run this command after changing sources.list to refresh the list of available software.

```
sudo apt update
```